# r fmsb package radarchart how to reverse the axis

Tags: r, web-crawler, radar-chart

I am having trouble reversing the axis in this example. I would like to start at 8 in he middle of the chart and then 1 at the top. At the moment the middle is 0 and end is 8.

`library(fmsb)`

Create data: note in High school for Jonathan:

```
data=as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 1:8 , 10 , replace=T) , ncol=10))
colnames(data)=c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music" , "R-coding", "data-viz" , "french" , "physic", "statistic", "sport" )
```

To use the fmsb package, I have to add 2 lines to the dataframe: the max and min of each topic to show on the plot!

```
data=rbind(rep(8,1) , rep(1,1) , data)
```

The default radar chart proposed by the library:

```
radarchart(data)
```

Custom the radarChart !

```
radarchart( data  , axistype=1 ,

        #custom polygon
        pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4 ,

        #custom the grid
        cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,8,2), cglwd=0.8,

        #custom labels
        vlcex=0.8
)
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, welcome to SO. Please learn how to properly format your posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to have a marking only for even numbered values,  but then you won't get 1 as an axis marker. I will make it go from 8 to 0, instead of from 8 to 1.  All that you need to do is reverse the axis limits that you specified and also reverse the axis labels.

```
data=as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 1:8 , 10 , replace=T) , ncol=10)) 
    colnames(data)=c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music" , 
    "R-coding", "data-viz" , "french" , "physic", "statistic", "sport" )

## Changes lower limit to 0
data=rbind(rep(8,1) , rep(0,1) , data)
radarchart(data)

## Reverse max and min (how points will be plotted)
data2 = data
data2[1:2,] = data2[2:1,]

radarchart( data2, axistype=1 ,
        #custom polygon
        pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4 ,

        #custom the grid
        cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", 

        # Reverse axis labeling
        caxislabels=seq(8,0,-2), cglwd=0.8,

        #custom labels
        vlcex=0.8

)
```

[image: Radar Chart]